# MVC File uploads collection is always null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload, razor

This was working and now for reasons unknown my file collection is null

VIEW

```
@section termimalContent {
      @using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "Terminals_Policies", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
      {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <fieldset>
          <legend>
            <h2>
              Create new policy</h2>
          </legend>
          <p>
            <strong>Assigning devices to Node:</strong> @Model.GroupName</p>
          <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PolicyName)
          </div>
          <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PolicyName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PolicyName)
          </div>
          <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PolicyType)
          </div>
          <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedItem, new SelectList(Model.PolicyType, "Value", "Text"),new {@class = "PackageDDL"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedItem)
          </div>

           @foreach (var pick in Model.PackageTypeItems)
           {
            <div class="editor-label">
              <label for="@pick.Name">
                @pick.Name:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
              <input class="text-box single-line" type="file" name="@pick.Name.Trim()" id="@pick.Name.Trim()" data-val="@pick.IsRequired.ToString().ToLower()" data-val-required="Please select a file" />
              @Html.ValidationMessage(pick.Name.Trim())
            </div>
           }

          @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.GroupId)
          @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.GroupName)
          <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
          </p>
        </fieldset>
      }
    }
```

HTML Generated

```
<form action="/Terminals_Policies/Add/1" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">    <fieldset>
      <legend>
        <h2>
          Create new policy</h2>
      </legend>
      <p>
        <strong>Assigning devices to Node:</strong> Root</p>
      <div class="editor-label">
        <label for="PolicyName">PolicyName</label>
      </div>
      <div class="editor-field">
        <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-length="Policy name cannot be longer than 50 characters." data-val-length-max="50" data-val-required="Please enter the policy name" id="PolicyName" name="PolicyName" type="text" value="" />
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="PolicyName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="editor-label">
        <label for="PolicyType">PolicyType</label>
      </div>
      <div class="editor-field">
        <select class="PackageDDL" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field SelectedItem must be a number." id="SelectedItem" name="SelectedItem"><option value="1">IT application</option>
<option value="3"> definition</option>
<option value="4">definition</option>
<option value="5">project</option>
<option value="6">relay schedules</option>
<option value="7">table data</option>
<option value="9">transfer definition</option>
<option value="10">firmware update request</option>
<option value="11"> firmware update request</option>
<option value="12">dat</option>
<option value="15"> firmware</option>
<option value="16"> hex</option>
<option value="17">project</option>
<option value="18">firmware</option>
</select>
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="SelectedItem" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
      </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
          <label for="IT application file                               ">
            IT application file                               :</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
          <input class="text-box single-line" type="file" name="IT application file" id="IT application file" data-val="true" data-val-required="Please select a file" />
          <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="IT application file" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>

      <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field GroupId must be a number." data-val-required="The GroupId field is required." id="GroupId" name="GroupId" type="hidden" value="1" />
      <input id="GroupName" name="GroupName" type="hidden" value="Root" />
      <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
      </p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Add(int id)
    {
      _polAdd = CreatePolicyAddModel(id);
      return View(_polAdd);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Add(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files, vmPoliciesAdd model)
    {
      _policyLogic.AddPolicyFile(files,model.PolicyName,(int)model.SelectedItem, "FILE");
      return View();
    }
```

On the post action of controller the colelction is empty, can anyone see an obvious mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Naming issue:

```
<input class="text-box single-line" type="file" name="IT application file" id="IT application file" data-val="true" data-val-required="Please select a file" />
```

Should of course be:

```
<input class="text-box single-line" type="file" name="files" id="IT application file" data-val="true" data-val-required="Please select a file" />
```

So fix your Razor code and make sure you have applied correct name to your file input if you expect the model binder to be able to bind to an action argument called `files`:

```
<input class="text-box single-line" type="file" name="files" id="@pick.Name.Trim()" data-val="@pick.IsRequired.ToString().ToLower()" data-val-required="Please select a file" />
```

Ah an by the way `id`'s cannot contain spaces. So you've got a broken HTML. The following seems wrong: `id="@pick.Name.Trim()"` as well.

Comment: Thankyou, I was being silly and assuming it would get files by the type rather than the supplied name

Comment: Oh no, the `name` is the only thing that matters.

Comment: Cool. Sometimes there will be multiple uploads, hence the Ienumerable. Can the upload controls all have the same name but a different id so it passes validators?

Comment: Of course. Please read the following article to familiarize yourself with the convention used by the default model binder when working with collections: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

Comment: Thanks again! The use of indexes for the name seems somethign im likely to use in the near future.